# PHP Properties Parser

Tags: php, find, strpos, strlen

Im making a property parser, and I want it to be able to parse a string of any length.

For example, I would like to be able to do the following call:

```
getDynamicProp("cheese:no;sauce:yes;chicken:brown", "sauce");
```

and have `"yes"` returned from it.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
function getDynamicProp($string , $property){
        $args = func_num_args();
        $args_val = func_get_args();
        $strlen = mb_strlen($string);


        $propstrstart = mb_strpos($string , $property . ":");

        $propstrend1 = substr($string , $propstrstart , )

        $propstrend = mb_strpos($string , ";" , $propstrstart);


        $finalvalue = substr($string , $propstrstart , $propstrend);
        $val = str_replace($property . ":" , "" , $finalvalue);
        $val2 = str_replace(";" , "" , $val);
        return $val2;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. The function uses explode to transform strings into arrays, which are more easily manipulable :

```
function getDynamicProp($string , $property){
  $the_result = array();
  $the_array = explode(";", $string);

  foreach ($the_array as $prop) {
    $the_prop = explode(":", $prop);
    $the_result[$the_prop[0]] = $the_prop[1];
  }
  return $the_result[$property];
}

$the_string = "cheese:no;sauce:yes;chicken:brown";
echo getDynamicProp($the_string,"cheese");
echo getDynamicProp($the_string,"sauce");
echo getDynamicProp($the_string,"chicken");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you make it over-complicated, or I didn't understand what you want.
I will go with regex instead of making position search.

Here is what I'll use:

```
function getDynamicProp($string , $property){
     if (preg_match('/(^|;)' . $property . ':(?P<value>[^;]+)/', $string, $matches)) {
          return $matches['value'];
     }
     return false;
}
```

Check [here](https://regex101.com/r/zX9iJ5/1) to visualize regex

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using `json_encode` and `json_decode` if you are in control of this string.  If not it's much easier like this:

```
function getDynamicProp($string, $property) {
    $string = str_replace(array(':',';'), array('=','&'), $string);
    parse_str($string, $result);
    return $result[$property];
}
```

Or store them as `cheese=no&sauce=yes&chicken=brown`.  Then it's even easier still.